# Eloquent retrieve on 2 table by date difference from one column and a given value

Tags: laravel, date, collections, eloquent, datediff

I have a problem with a query, I'm using Laravel 8 and my two tables are as follows:

1. peoples:

   - id
   - name
   - date_of_birth (DATE)
   - is_visible
   - other fields
2. categories:

   - id
   - name
   - min_age
   - max_age

I would like to select all people with the category name if the difference between the `date_of_birth` and the last day of the current year is between `min_age` and `max_age` and divide the collection by category name.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how is the `categories` table related to the `peoples` table? Is there a foreign key somewhere? Can you give an example of a category's min_age and max_age values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the following:

- There are no models.
- `peoples.date_of_birth` has the following format: (YYYY-MM-DD)
- `categories.min_age` and `categories.max_age` are integers.

```php
$categories = DB::table('categories')->get();
$people = DB::table('people')->cursor();

$people = $people->groupBy(function ($person) use ($categories) {
    // datediff in years using Carbon
    $dob = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $person->date_of_birth); // use $person->date_of_birth directly if it's already a Carbon object
    $years = (int) $dob->diff(now()->endOfYear())->format('%Y');

    $category = $categories->filter(fn($category) => ($category->min_age <= $years && $years <= $category->max_age));

    return $category->isEmpty() ? 'Category not found' : $category->first()->name;
})
->collect();
```

Comment: I am sorry to reply so late, there is a model for people and one for categories. In the people model I have an age attribute and I would like to obtain each category with all the people belonging to that category (min_age <= age <= max_age). some advice? maybe I'm still too tied to standard php-mysql ...

Comment: The code should work the same. Use `People::...` instead of `DB::table('people')->...` and `Category::...` instead of `DB::table('categories')->...`